# Calculate length of character array in a list in R

Tags: r

I tried to separate the words of a sentence as different elements of an array like this:

words_from_sentence <- strsplit("I am going out Brother", " ")

I now want to get the length of the array of words and want to access each word by index number of the array. However, I end up getting a single list of length 1. Please advise.

typeof(words_from_sentence)

> List

length(words_from_sentence)

> 1

length(words_from_sentence[1])

> 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double bracket indexing when trying to grab an element from a list.

```
length(words_from_sentence[[1]])
```

Comment: I need the length of each character array in the list, not just one of them. How do I do that without looping though it.
EDIT: I posted my answer after figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
nchar(list_of_char_arrays)
```

As a bonus, it will return the names of each element too.